# Installing New Undermount Sink Under Existing Countertop

Tags: kitchens, sink, kitchen-sink, kitchen-counters

I'm doing initial research into replacing our existing sink.  Pictured below: [image]

We absolutely hate the double basin sink since the bigger side doesn't have the garbage disposal and barely gets used.  That being said, we're looking to replace the sink with a single basin; however, we won't be redoing the countertops so it'll be need to be installed with the stone countertops already in place.

My question for the community is: what should a noob homeowner get looked at first and who should I be working with?  Should I get someone to come and measure the dimensions in detail? Should I confirm whether or not it's a huge risk for the countertop with a new install?

A few details:

- Sink width from left to right is a little more than 30"
- Sink length (front to back) for the left basin is about 19"
- Sink length for the right basin is about 16.5" and is slightly more shallow
- On the underside, it looks like a combo of glue and screws were used to mount the sink to the countertop
- I cannot find any identifying information about the sink manufacturer

Please feel free to ask clarifying questions and I'll add details in the description.  Thanks a ton for your help.

Edits:

Example of single basin sink in similar shape: https://www.build.com/houzer-mh-3200/s1188609?uid=2848522

Adding a picture of the bottom mounting:
[image]

Comment: That's going to be an expensive case of hate, as you'll almost certainly need to get the (stone?) countertop re-cut for a single-bowl, and it's unclear if you'll have the room for the faucet on deck behind that. At least I've never seen a single-bowl with the bowl necked in like this double-bowl, anyway.

Comment: A picture of the bottom mounting would be helpful. The biggest issue will be that for a single basin, they'll have to enlarge the hole in the counter top and in doing so, will run into the hole for the faucet mount. Not sure how they'd be able to fill that hole. Drilling a new hole for the faucet mount won't be a problem.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I can post a few examples I've found through searching, they don't seem to be uncommon.

Comment: Well, that makes it more practical, then.

Comment: @FreeMan - added a picture of the underside mounting for ya.

Comment: "hate the double basin sink since the bigger side doesn't have the garbage disposal and barely gets used" Have you considered just moving the garbage disposal over to the larger side?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a plumber would be able to handle the sink replacement for you. I doubt a cabinet/counter shop would want to do that part.

They would probably use a putty knife to slide through the sealant between the bottom of the stone and the top of the bowl. Then they'd undo the bolts and the basin would come right down. Scrape all the sealant residue off the bottom of the stone and it should be ready to seal & bolt the new basin in place.

Finding a new sink to match is probably going to be the most difficult portion of the task. You could have a plumber come in to measure everything for you, but I'm willing to bet you could do it yourself. Besides, I don't think a plumber would be all that interested in helping you shop. By eyeball, the sink you linked doesn't look like it would fit, though. It looks like the radius at the top left (at least) is all wrong.

I'd suggest that you hit up your local home decorating and/or plumbing supply stores (not the local branch of the national big-box store). Bring in *exact* measurements of the sink and they'd be able to help you out. Some might even come to your place to do the measurements for you.

You could probably make a cardboard template of the counter top opening by taping down a big piece of cardboard (recent amazon deliver box, all opened up?) over the sink, then use a regular steak knife to plunge through near the edge of the sink. Cut to the edge, then follow the edge of the counter while your cutting the cardboard. Your steak knife should cut the cardboard well enough yet not damage the counter (depends on how soft the stone it). A box cutter would cut the box more easily but *could* also cut into the stone. Test it on the bottom of the stone near the sink to be sure. Take the template with you when shopping to see if it matches anything available.

Comment: A big sheet of paper and just scribbling across the edge with a pencil (ala gravestone rubbings) will get the shape/size without any cut or scratch risk.

Comment: True, @Ecnerwal, but a piece of cardboard will be more sturdy for taking to stores. It'll last longer. If the stone will resist a cut in general, it'll survive this process just fine - I was recommending an overabundance of caution because I know that _some_ stone countertops can be damaged.